# jquery jqgrid. Add form disabled in empty grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have popup form which starts with an empty jqgrid. The user presses the + icon to insert a new record.  The default jqgrid form is displayed but all of the field are disabled. i.e. will not accept focus or allow data entry.
I enclose the colModel code which has editable set to true.

Is there a problem with jqgrid when the grid is empty and the add form is displayed?
Thanks

```
            $("#import_list").jqGrid({
        url: "ajax_get_awb_for_adding_import.php",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colModel: [
            { name: "id", align: "center" ,label:'id',hidden:true,key:true},                
            //{ name: 'Load', align: "center",editable: true,edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "1:0" }, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false} },
            { name: "mawb_pfx",  align: "center" ,label:'AWB PFX',editable: true},
            { name: "mawb_num", align: "center" ,label:'AWB Number',editable: true},
            { name: "pces",align: "center" ,label:'Pces',editable: true},
            { name: "wt", align: "center" ,label:'Wt',editable: true}                               
        ],      


$("#import_list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager3",
        {
        del:true,
        edit:true,
        add:true,
        search:false            
        },
        {width:450},        
        {
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
                alert (response.responseText);
                }   
    });
```

[Jqgrid add form disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDI3k.png)

Comment: I have a screen shot but can figure out how to add it to this post!

Comment: Can you please post the other things related to the problem - I mean could you  include all the javascript and css files. If you can prepare a example in jsfiddle by example, that would be great